# Pose mode moves bone before clicking 'g'

Tags: customization, pose-mode

When I select a control in Pose mode, in order to rotate (or scale) I have to first click 'r' (or 's). To move it, I don't have to click 'g', I can move the bone immediately. However, I make a lot of unintended moves (like pose 'typos') because it will register a movement when I try to click off to deselect the control, or select a different control.

How do I change Blender so I have to click 'g' in order to move a control or bone?